# Linux system call from kernel crashing (weird offset)

Tags: c, linux, assembly, linux-kernel, att

I'm trying to call a system call from a kernel module, I have this code:

```
    set_fs( get_ds() );    // lets our module do the system-calls 


    // Save everything before systemcalling

    asm ("     push    %rax     "); 
    asm  ("     push    %rdi     "); 
    asm  ("     push    %rcx     "); 
    asm  ("     push    %rsi     "); 
    asm  ("     push    %rdx     "); 
    asm  ("     push    %r10     "); 
    asm  ("     push    %r8      "); 
    asm  ("     push    %r9      "); 
    asm  ("     push    %r11     "); 
    asm  ("     push    %r12     "); 
    asm  ("     push    %r15     "); 
    asm  ("     push    %rbp     "); 
    asm  ("     push    %rbx     "); 


    // Invoke the long sys_mknod(const char __user *filename, int mode, unsigned dev);

    asm volatile ("     movq    $133, %rax     "); // system call number

    asm volatile ("    lea    path(%rip), %rdi     "); // path is char path[] = ".."

    asm volatile ("     movq    mode, %rsi     "); // mode is S_IFCHR | ...

    asm volatile ("     movq    dev, %rdx     ");  // dev is 70 >> 8

    asm volatile ("     syscall     "); 


      // POP EVERYTHING 

    asm ("     pop     %rbx     "); 
    asm ("     pop        %rbp     "); 
    asm ("     pop     %r15     "); 
    asm ("     pop        %r12     "); 
    asm ("     pop        %r11     "); 
    asm ("     pop        %r9      "); 
    asm ("     pop        %r8      "); 
    asm ("     pop        %r10     "); 
    asm ("     pop        %rdx     "); 
    asm ("     pop        %rsi     "); 
    asm ("     pop        %rcx     "); 
    asm ("     pop        %rdi     "); 
    asm ("     pop     %rax     "); 



    set_fs( savedFS );    // restore the former address-limit value
```

This code isn't working and is crashing the system down (it's a kernel module).

The dump of that piece of code with relocation infos is:

```
  2c:    50                      push  %rax 
  2d:    57                      push  %rdi 
  2e:    51                      push  %rcx 
  2f:    56                      push  %rsi 
  30:    52                      push  %rdx 
  31:    41 52                    push  %r10 
  33:    41 50                    push  %r8 
  35:    41 51                    push  %r9 
  37:    41 53                    push  %r11 
  39:    41 54                    push  %r12 
  3b:    41 57                    push  %r15 
  3d:    55                      push  %rbp 
  3e:    53                      push  %rbx 
  3f:    48 c7 c0 85 00 00 00     mov    $0x85,%rax 
  46:    48 8d 3d 00 00 00 00     lea    0x0(%rip),%rdi        # 4d <init_module+0x4d> 
            49: R_X86_64_PC32    path-0x4 
  4d:    48 83 c7 04              add    $0x4,%rdi 
  51:    48 8b 34 25 00 00 00     mov    0x0,%rsi 
  58:    00 
            55: R_X86_64_32S    mode 
  59:    48 8b 14 25 00 00 00     mov    0x0,%rdx 
  60:    00 
            5d: R_X86_64_32S    dev 
  61:    0f 05                    syscall 
  63:    5b                      pop    %rbx 
  64:    5d                      pop    %rbp 
  65:    41 5f                    pop    %r15 
  67:    41 5c                    pop    %r12 
  69:    41 5b                    pop    %r11 
  6b:    41 59                    pop    %r9 
  6d:    41 58                    pop    %r8 
  6f:    41 5a                    pop    %r10 
  71:    5a                      pop    %rdx 
  72:    5e                      pop    %rsi 
  73:    59                      pop    %rcx 
  74:    5f                      pop    %rdi 
  75:    58                      pop    %rax
```

I'm wondering.. why is there a -0x4 offset in the 
49: R_X86_64_PC32    path-0x4  ?

I mean: mode and dev should be resolved automatically without problems, but what about the path? Why the -0x4 offset?

I tried to "compensate it" with

lea    0x0(%rip),%rdi // this somehow adds a -0x4 offset
add $0x4, %rdi
....

but the code still crashed.

Where am I getting wrong?

Comment: You cannot call a system call from inside the kernel. The kernel is providing system calls to applications. What do you want to really do? Can't you avoid working in kernel land?

Comment: That's why I put the set_fs( get_ds() ); that should increase the segment limit which can invoke system calls. It's an exercise for an exam (http://cs.usfca.edu/~cruse/cs635/) so I need to figure out how to do it with amd64

Comment: From the `syscall` calling convention comment: `rcx  return address for syscall/sysret, C arg3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess as to what's going on here is a stack problem. Unlike `int $0x80`, the `syscall` instruction will not set up a stack for the kernel. If you look at the actual code from `system_call:`, you'll see something like `SWAPGS_UNSAFE_STACK`. The meat of this macro is the SwapGS instruction - see page 152 [here](http://support.amd.com/us/Processor_TechDocs/24593_APM_v2.pdf). When kernel mode is entered, the kernel needs a way to pull a pointer to its data structures, and this instruction lets it do precisely this. It does so by swapping the user `%gs` register with a value saved in a model-specific register, from which it can then pull the kernel-mode stack.

You could imagine that once the `syscall` entry point is invoked, this swap is producing the wrong value since you were already in kernel mode, and the kernel starts trying to use a bogus stack. You might try invoking SwapGS manually,making the kernel's SwapGS result in what it expects, and see if that works.

Comment: segmentation fault, dammit. Anyway I think you're right, there's a lot going on and I should read all the syscall routine to figure out what's wrong. A lot of time indeed.

Comment: sorry, I gave you the wrong link above. should be fixed now. I would also look at the pseudocode in the AMD spec for the syscall instruction [here](http://lars.nocrew.org/computers/processors/x86-64/24594.pdf) on page 345. At the very least, this will help you 
understand what linux is doing at the system_call routine.

btw, what exactly was happening when you said it was crashing? It caused the machine to hang? printed a kernel oops? etc. If it's not hanging the machine you could try running dmesg and looking for something odd

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can't do that in a such way. See the [comment](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.2.11/arch/x86/kernel/entry_64.S#L432) before `system_call`:

```
 /*
  * Register setup:
  * rax  system call number
  * rdi  arg0
  * rcx  return address for syscall/sysret, C arg3
  * rsi  arg1
  * rdx  arg2
  * r10  arg3    (--> moved to rcx for C)
  * r8   arg4
  * r9   arg5
  * r11  eflags for syscall/sysret, temporary for C
  * r12-r15,rbp,rbx saved by C code, not touched.
  *
  * Interrupts are off on entry.
  * Only called from user space.
  *
  * XXX  if we had a free scratch register we could save the RSP into the stack frame
  *      and report it properly in ps. Unfortunately we haven't.
  *
  * When user can change the frames always force IRET. That is because
  * it deals with uncanonical addresses better. SYSRET has trouble
  * with them due to bugs in both AMD and Intel CPUs.
  */
```

So, you can't call the `syscall` from the kernel. But you can try to use `int $0x80` for that purposes. As I see it `kernel_execve` stub uses that [trick](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.2.11/arch/x86/kernel/sys_i386_32.c#L31)

Comment: Can I call int 0x80 from a 64 bit program? Would it work? And I need to put 32-bit system calls index in rax, isn't right?

Comment: Turns out that I CAN NOT use int 0x80 in a 64 bit kernel module. I'm wondering if there is any kind of VA-whence-protection mechanism..

Comment: Why do you need to make the `syscall`? Can you try to call `sys_mknod` directly?..

Comment: nope, sys_mknod is not "documented", you shouldn't use it as long as you're not in user mode

Comment: Do you think that calling a syscall from the kernel is a good and documented way?